# Log In from Toolstrip Menu Item and UserControl Button in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, authentication

I cannot figure out the solution.

Here's the brief description.

I have the main form called "frmMain" which has a MenuStrip which contains a ToolStripMenuItem called "mnuFile", which again contains a ToolStripMenuItem called "mnuLogIn".

At the same time, the main form also contains a panel called "panel2" which will hold the instance of the usercontrol called "uc_MainMenu" when the form loads.
That usercontrol has a few buttons and one of which is the buttons called "btnLogIn".

The Structure is that I want the user to be able to log in if he enters the correct username and password either from "mnuLogIn" or "btnLogIn".
When one of those buttons is clicked, "frmLogIn" will appear.

When the log in is successful, both "mnuLogIn" or "btnLogIn" will change their text from "LogIn" to "LogOut".

I wrote the method for Logging-in in the main form as follows.

```
    internal void mnuLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          ShowLogIn();

    }


    internal void ShowLogIn()
    {

        if (this.mnuLogIn.Text == "LogOut" )
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to LogOut?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                 mnuLogIn.Text = "LogIn";
                 ShowMenu("");
                 obj_uc_MainMenu.Log_Out_Button = new Button();        
            }
            return;
       }


        frmLogin obj_frmLogin = new frmLogin();


        //followed by checking the username and password 
        //the procedure repeated until the log-in is successful

        mnuLogIn.Text = "LogOut";

        obj_uc_MainMenu.Log_In_Button = new Button();      
   }
```

In the usercontrol "uc_MainMenu"

```
public Button Log_In_Button
    {
        get { return btnLogIn; }

        set { btnLogIn.Text = "LOGOUT"; }
    }



private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        frmMain obj_frmMain = new frmMain();           
        obj_frmMain.mnuLogIn_Click(sender,e);

      }
```

Running this code

1)"mnuLogIn" Logging-in

When I tried to log in via the "mnuLogIn" button, everything is fine. Both the "mnuLogIn" and "btnLogIn" inside the obj_uc_MainMenu changed their text from "LogIn" to "LogOut".

2)"btnLogIn" Logging-in

When I tried to log in via the "btnLogIn" button, the "frmLogin" appeared. It worked perfectly for the checking the username and password steps. But after I clicked the LogIn button from the "frmLogin" dialog box, nothing happened. Neither "mnuLogIn" nor "btnLogIn" changed their text.

What is going on?

Oh I forgot to mention, the DialogResult of the LogIn button from the "frmLogin" has been set to OK. So there is no code inside the "frmLogin".

Comment: Classic problem. You call _new frmMain_ and then act on that instance. You are not changing the frmMain instance already on the screen but the one you have just created and this instance is never shown. To understand better what's happening here try to add _obj_frmMain.Show();_ after the call to _obj_frmMain.mnuLogIn_Click(sender,e);_ inside you user control button click event handler

Comment: @Steve Oh I see! Is there any way to show the changes?  I cannot declare static to the main form since it is a derived class from the "Form".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to change your code to this approach.

```
// This should be public to be callable from the usercontrol
public void ShowLogIn()
{
    if (this.mnuLogIn.Text == "LogOut" )
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to LogOut?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
             mnuLogIn.Text = "LogIn";
             ShowMenu("");

             // Call the user control to adjust its internal status
             obj_uc_MainMenu.SetLoginStatus();
        }
   }
   else
   {
       using(frmLogin obj_frmLogin = new frmLogin())
       {
            if(obj_frmLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
               // Check the username and password and if everythin ok then

               mnuLogIn.Text = "LogOut";
               // Again call the usercontrol to adjust its status
               obj_uc_MainMenu.SetLogoutStatus()
           }
       }
    }
}


public void SetLoginStatus()
{
    btnLogIn.Text = "LOGIN"; 
}
public void SetLogoutStatusStatus()
{
    btnLogIn.Text = "LOGOUT"; 
}
private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the current instance of frmMain from the OpenForms collection
    frmMain obj_frmMain = Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmMain>();           

    // Should not be required, but better to be safe....
    if(obj_frmMain != null) 
       // Call the public method to run the login process
       obj_frmMain.ShowLogin();
}
```